# How to dispose form rows over more columns

Tags: python, pyside

I want to dispose my forms fields over more columns. Yet I can't find the proper way to do it.

Please consider the following MWE

```
import sys, time
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 175)

    def SetLayout(self):
        formLayout = QFormLayout(self)
        labelAuthor = QLabel("Author")
        txtAuthor = QLineEdit()
        labelTitle = QLabel("Title")
        txtTitle = QLineEdit()
        labelBodytext1 = QLabel("Bodytext 1")
        txtBodytext1 = QTextEdit()
        labelBodytext2 = QLabel("Bodytext 2")
        txtBodytext2 = QTextEdit()
        labelBodytext3 = QLabel("Bodytext 3")
        txtBodytext3 = QTextEdit()

        formLayout.addRow(labelAuthor, txtAuthor)
        formLayout.addRow(labelTitle, txtTitle)
        formLayout.addRow(labelBodytext1, txtBodytext1)
        formLayout.addRow(labelBodytext2, txtBodytext2)
        formLayout.addRow(labelBodytext3, txtBodytext3)

        self.setLayout(formLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainWindow = MainWindow()
        mainWindow.SetLayout()
        mainWindow.show()
        myApp.exec_()
        sys.exit(0)
    except NameError:
        print("Name Error:", sys.exc_info()[1])
    except SystemExit:
        print("Closing Window...")
    except Exception:
        print(sys.exc_info()[1])
```

All fields are aligned in one column. Instead I would like to dispose them over 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [FormLayout](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QFormLayout.html) says it's fixed to two columns width. Use [GridLayout](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QGridLayout.html) instead.

See official BasicLayouts [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-basiclayouts.html) for more information how to use QGridLayout.